# jQuery AJAX Call to Server Side Method Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to call a server side method from a jQuery AJAX call but it is not working.  Any help would be appreciated.

jQuery call is:

```
$('#btnAddAttachment').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Ticket.aspx/AddAttachment",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }); 
});
```

Server Side code is:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public void AddAttachment()
    {
        string name = txtAttach.FileName;
        string strPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["crmWorkspacesDir"].ToString() + txtTicketNum.Text + "\\";

        if (!Directory.Exists(strPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath);

        txtAttach.SaveAs(strPath + name);

        DataTable oDT = (DataTable)ViewState["attachments"];
        DataRow oDR = oDT.NewRow();
        oDR["File"] = strPath + name;
        oDR["Size"] = new FileInfo(strPath + name).Length / 1000;
        oDT.Rows.Add(oDR);

        grdAttachments.DataSource =  oDT;
        grdAttachments.DataBind();

    }
```

It appears that the call is getting back to the Ticket.aspx page but not getting to the AddAttachment method.  Does anyone see anything wrong with the jQuery?
Thanks!

Comment: definitely an asp issue

Comment: Put success and error method to see if eror comes

Comment: If I'm right, you method at the codebehind need be static.

Comment: What happens if you browse to Ticket.aspx/AddAttachment?

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing a webmethod in code behind, it should be static. Change your web method like this

```
public static void AddAttachment()
{
    string name = txtAttach.FileName;
    string strPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["crmWorkspacesDir"].ToString() + txtTicketNum.Text + "\\";

    if (!Directory.Exists(strPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(strPath);

    txtAttach.SaveAs(strPath + name);

    DataTable oDT = (DataTable)ViewState["attachments"];
    DataRow oDR = oDT.NewRow();
    oDR["File"] = strPath + name;
    oDR["Size"] = new FileInfo(strPath + name).Length / 1000;
    oDT.Rows.Add(oDR);

    grdAttachments.DataSource =  oDT;
    grdAttachments.DataBind();

}
```